# Tab Bar Icon display issue in universal app

Tags: xcode, uitabbaritem, ios5.1

I have an odd issue that's driving me nuts by now. Hopefully someone here can help me or ran into something similar. I've searched up and down but didn't find anything similar.

I am creating a universal app (Xcode 4.3.3) with storyboard including a UITabBar with 4 icons. The icons are from the free glyphish set, and look just fine in the iPhone simulator. In the iPad simulator, however, they look enlarged, and only about the top half is visible in the tabbar.

In addition to the original icon, I also created @2X, ~ipad and @2X~ipad versions (I did this for pretty much all art via batch in Photoshop). However, the icons look the same (i.e. too large) in the iPad simulator even when I remove these other versions and only keep the glyphish original.

I looked at the storyboard source code, I changed around a bunch of Tabbar and TabbarItem settings in the storyboard, nothing seems to help. HELP!

EDIT: I just noticed that the icons look fine in the iPad (Retina) simulator!?!?

SOLVED IT:
OK, solved it myself. Not sure which of these steps did it, but here's what I did:

- delete the app from the simulator
- Clean the Project
- Recompile and Run

Now the icons display correctly. Go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT: OK, solved it myself. Not sure which of these steps did it, but here's what I did:

1. Delete the app from the simulator
2. Clean the Project
3. Recompile and Run

Now the icons display correctly. Go figure.